# What things are needed to be modified when publishing update version of app android

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android . I just published an app called " Event Database "

Now I am ready with the update version of the app and want it to be updated in the market

What things are to be altered when publishing update version of app android .

As far as I know ,: I should change the following code :

1. android:versionCode = for developers
2. database version  =  for developers
3. android:versionName  = for user

Is anything else still remaining that need to be change

Pls suggest me

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html

Comment: This is very much confusing ... help me with simple way

Comment: @Prachur ------ Even if there is no change in database , then also I need to upgrade " database version "

Comment: No. If only any change is made to database then only you need to upgrade it. Otherwise VersionCode and number are sufficient. And make sure use the old release key for the app.

Comment: @Prachur ------ Don't mistake me , a small doubt . If I did , then will it cause any problem to the user ??

Comment: Depends upon what your onupgrade method has. If you are dropping table then it would delete all data.

Comment: If I add a column in a table then ??

Comment: Then please do update the Database version.